# Maven 2.2.1 attached tests. Issue -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, maven-2

I am using the plugin to attached tests in the test of another module.

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

And in the module where the jar is required:

```xml
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

It has been very useful to me, but **I have found a problem**: When I execute **"clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true"**, also **the dependency test-jar is required and the proccess fails**

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, because `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` just makes the maven junit plugins (surefire and failsafe) not execute - it prevents them from running any tests.

it does *NOT* prevent maven from trying to "collect" all of your test-scoped dependenies. maven still collects all of them.

if you want optional dependencies (regardless of what scope) you should read about [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) - you could define a profile in which this dependency will be defined and then maven will try and get it only if you activate the profile (from the command line, for example)

Comment: So, what is about the comment in the maven site? "If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire ..." with this comment I supposed that compilation would be avoided, http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: ...it'll still try and get the dependencies. it just wont do anything with them.

Comment: I have found the reported issue to solve this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4192

Comment: @JaviPedrera - been open since 2009. i wouldnt wait :-)

Comment: haha, I know it and I wont wait, I will try with a workaround, thank you

Comment: I ended up using `-D skipTests` as suggested in the issue Javi posted and that works for me

Answer (score 2):

`-Dmaven.skip.test` or `-DskipTests` just skips the test execution, it still compiles test classes so it needs test dependencies

If you want to skip the compilation of test classes, you can configure maven compiler plugin to do so, more helpful would be to create separate build profile and skip compilation on demand by specifying special build profile

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```